# Odoo (OpenERP8) connection failed with Postgre

Tags: postgresql, connection, odoo

I just installed Odoo in Linux Mint. The installation process was correct. I  have lost the database data when I installed Postgre and when I start openerp-server and load localhost:8069, the webpage displays: 
"The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application."

And in Odoo log the error is:

```
2014-08-10 11:02:55,941 4924 ERROR ? openerp.addons.bus.bus: Bus.loop error, sleep and retry
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxxx/odoo/openerp/addons/bus/bus.py", line 136, in run
    self.loop()
  File "/home/xxxx/odoo/openerp/addons/bus/bus.py", line 114, in loop
    with openerp.sql_db.db_connect('postgres').cursor() as cr:
  File "/home/xxxx/odoo/openerp/sql_db.py", line 565, in cursor
    return Cursor(self.__pool, self.dbname, serialized=serialized)
  File "/home/xxxx/odoo/openerp/sql_db.py", line 176, in __init__
    self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn(dbname))
  File "/home/xxxx/odoo/openerp/sql_db.py", line 458, in _locked
    return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/xxxx/odoo/openerp/sql_db.py", line 521, in borrow
    result = psycopg2.connect(dsn=dsn, connection_factory=PsycoConnection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2-2.5.3-py2.7-linux-i686.egg/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

how can I correct it and configure correctly the data connection between Odoo and Postgre? 
I'm new with these programs and thank a detailed step by step help to solve :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: look in your pg_hba.conf in your postgres folder http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33928585/python-and-postgresql-operationalerror-fe-sendauth-no-password-supplied

Comment: The message `fe_sendauth: no password supplied` is coming from the postgresql server so you do get connected but you do not supply password while the server seems to expect it. Either supply the password or switch to trust in `pg_hba.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute a --help command for known db parameters.

Database related options:
    -d DB_NAME, --database=DB_NAME
                        specify the database name
    -r DB_USER, --db_user=DB_USER
                        specify the database user name
    -w DB_PASSWORD, --db_password=DB_PASSWORD
                        specify the database password
    --db_port=DB_PORT   specify the database port

example:
openerp-server -d DB -r openerp -w 1234 --db_port=5432